# custom head color only the text but not the whole box

Tags: macros, sectioning

I am trying to color a custom heading `\resheading` that is defined as

```
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{-15pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}\colorbox{shadecolorB}{\bf \large #1}}%
    \end{shaded} 
 }
}
```

The above code colors only the text, where I wanted to color the whole line or box. Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{times}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{2pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{1}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
%\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.83}  % Inner background color of title bars
%\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.86}
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{RGB}{246,213,216}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{-15pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}\colorbox{shadecolorB}{\bf \large #1}}%
    \end{shaded} 
 }
}


\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Professional Experience}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: My test of your MWE, that text is not colored but it is black, but the box, in which it is, is has fill color red (shadecolorB). Can you clarify your problem, Maybe with a sketch, which will show desired result?

Answer (score 2):

What I understand, I'm not sure.
I suggest using `tikz` The documentation is Tikz & pgf Manual for Version 3.1.10. It can be found on ctan https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

1. I create a rectangle with shading (section 2.14 Shading (p.39)).
2. I create a node (section 2.21 Adding Text (p.45)).

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

   \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{showframe}% <- comment ine the final document
   \usepackage{tikz}

   \definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{1}
   \definecolor{shadecolorB}{RGB}{246,213,216}

   \newcommand{\resheading}[1]
   {%
   \noindent
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shade[left color=shadecolorB,right color=shadecolor]
       (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\baselineskip);
       \node[right]at (0,0.5\baselineskip){\bfseries\large #1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }

   \begin{document}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \resheading{Professional Experience}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: pgfmanual 2.14? recent one is 3.1.10 ...

Comment: @Zarko, I wasn't clear enough, I meant section 2.14 Shading

Comment: I see, it will be fine, if you would clarify this.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you, I followed your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

With use of `tblr` table is simple:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{RGB}{246,213,216}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\newcommand{\resheading}[1]
{\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{X[l, font=\large\bfseries, bg=shadecolorB]}
   #1
\end{tblr}%
\medskip            % if after \resheading is needed some vertical space
}

\begin{document}
\resheading{Professional Experience}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate document pages layout)